# How to perform concatenation of lines based on a condition in vim?

Tags: vim, concatenation, vi

In vim, how can I run the following logic over my file:

> If the line `n` not end with a semicolon, concatenate lines `n` and `n + 1`.

I have files which have broken SQL statements:

> **broken version**

```
select * from tab1;
select col4, col5 from
 tab5;
insert into
 tab6 values(
2, 4);
```

> **required version**

```
select * from tab1;
select col4, col5 from tab5;
insert into tab6 values(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:v/;$/normal J
```

You may have to run it several times.

EDIT: Here is a solution that solves lines split on multiple (>2) lines:

```
%s/^\s*$\|\([^;]\)\s*\n/\1/g
```

Note: Empty lines are kept, but trimmed, thanks to the ^\s*$

Comment: thanks, but this `several` would run into 1000s for me. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: That's what I was looking for. :g is not the solution. I edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless "dirty" "hack" ;-)

```
:1,$ join
```

this join every line on the file to a single one, but you can adjust the range...

```
:s:;:&\r:g
```

this replaces every ; with a ; and a newline

HTH